# Crear un Cuadrado en JAVA

Tags: java

**Crear un cuadrado en java** ,donde el usuario ingrese el tamaño del cuadrado ; pero este se va intercalar con "**@**" y " * ".
crearlo por medio de ciclo for y utilizando estructuras condicionales

Por ejemplo, si el usuario ingresa 7, esta sera la imagen que se mostrara en pantalla:

[image]

Lo que intente:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Cuadrado{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Por favor ingrese el tamaño del cuadrado: ");
        int n = teclado.nextInt();

        if(n >= 0 && n<=50) {
            //Linea superior
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                System.out.print("*");

            }
            System.out.println();

            //centro de la forma
            for(int i = 0; i < n-2; i++) {
                System.out.print("*");


                for(int j = 0; j < n-2; j++) {
                    System.out.print("@");
                }

                System.out.println("*"); 
            }

            //Linea inferior
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

                System.out.print("*");

            }
        }else {
            System.out.println("Error. El dato a ingresar de "
                    + "estar entre 0 y 50");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado?, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio , es importante agregar lo que has realizado o investigado, por favor modifica tu pregunta, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías crear un array con los caracteres que se intercalan y luego una matriz de `char` para rellenarla con dichos caracteres. Algo así:

```
public class Cuadrado{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Por favor ingrese el tamaño del cuadrado: ");
        int n = teclado.nextInt();

        char[][] cuadro = new char[n][n];
        char[] caracteres = {'*', '@'};

        for(int capa = 0; capa < n/2 + 1; capa++) {
            for (int i = capa; i < n - capa; i++) {
                cuadro[capa][i] = caracteres[capa % caracteres.length];
                cuadro[i][capa] = caracteres[capa % caracteres.length];
                cuadro[n - capa - 1][i] = caracteres[capa % caracteres.length];
                cuadro[i][n - capa - 1] = caracteres[capa % caracteres.length];
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\n----- RESULTADO -----");

        for (char[] array : cuadro) {
            for (char caracter : array) {
                System.out.print(caracter);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }

        System.out.println("---------------------");

        teclado.close();
    }
}
```

Así si necesitas intercalar más caracteres y no solamente 2 entonces simplemente los agregas al array.

Comment: Estaba haciendo el ejercicio cuando te he visto. Añadiría la sentencia de cerrar el escáner y una comprobación inicial de que el número que se pide sea mayor que 2. No hay necesidad de crear un cuadrado de dimensiones menores

Comment: @daenius. Cierto, se me había pasado ese detalle de cerrar el Scanner.

Comment: sí, está bien es funcional , pero como una de las condiciones era solo utilizar ciclo (For) y (Estructuras Condicionales).